# How can I avoid an infinite recursion loop when calling an API endpoint using axios to update a component in React

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm building a react App to learn the basics and I'm stuck with the chart update after calling the API.

The App I'm building has a weather API and makes call to that API endpoint to fetch data given a location and a time range (last 30 days, last 7 days, etc.)

I have three components:

- **WeatherVisualization** which is the Root component. It has state.
- **LocationSelector** and TimeranteSelector, which render the select inputs and inform the root component of the selected option (by means of a callback passed in props). It is stateless
- **TemperatureChart** which renders the chart. It is stateless since it recieves the data from the Root component.

The following picture illustrates the description.

[image]

##### The problem

When I click on any of the selectors, the state of WeatherVisualization is changed, thus the **componentDidMount** method is executed.

There I make the API call, and when the date is ready is passed to the **TemperatureChart**. My problem is that, since I store the data in the state the componentDidMount in an infinite recursion loop.

Here is the code for the componentDidUpdate method.

```js
componentDidUpdate() {
        axios.get(`/weather/api/location/${this.state.location}/${this.state.timerangeId}/temperature/`).then((res) => {
                    this.setState({data: res.data});
                }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }
```

How should I reachitecture my App? I found a bizarre working solution but I'm sure there is a more elegant one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `prevState` and `this.state` to make sure API only call when `timerangeId` change

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
  if(prevState.timerangeId !== this.state.timerangeId){
    axios.get(`/weather/api/location/${this.state.location}/${this.state.timerangeId}/temperature/`).then((res) => {
      this.setState({data: res.data});
    }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }
}
```